# drop down choice in Java/Javascript/JSP

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, sql, jsp

I'm creating a simple web application in which the users can choose a room to book. In particular I should give the opportunity to choose about different type or room (for instance I have classic room, superior room, deluxe room ).
I have created this form for the others features of the room booking:

```
<label class="Labeltext" >Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name"  style="margin-left: 238px; margin-top: 0px;"/>
                <br><br>
             <label class="Labeltext" >Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email"  style="margin-left: 239px; margin-top: 0px;"/>
                <br><br>
            <label class="Labeltext" >Arrival Date:</label>
            <input type="date" name="arrivaldate"  style="margin-left: 180px; margin-top: 0px;"/>
                <br><br>
            <label class="Labeltext"  margin-top: -20px;">Departure Date:</label>
            <input type="date" name="departuredate" style="margin-left: 146px;" />
                <br><br>
            <label class="Labeltext" >Total No. of Persons:</label>
            <input type="text" name="person"  style="margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 0px;"/>
                <br><br>

            <label class="Labeltext" >Total No. of Rooms:</label>
            <input type="text" name="rooms"  style="margin-left: 112px; margin-top: 0px;"/>
            <br><br>
```

Now I have the this 2 databases:

> HotelBooking
>   with this parameters:
>   cid, cname,email,arrival_date,departure_date,person,room,comment,status,id
>   and the second one:
>   Hotel
>   with:
>   Deluxe,Classic,Superior

In your opinion how can I insert the features for the room ( Deluxe, Classic, Superior ) in the .jsp file? I have try with a drop down menu, but I don't know to implement it. ( Because I can't use php solutions ).
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using EL then use:

```
<select name="room">
                <option value=0>Select one</option>
                    <c:forEach items="${rooms}" var="product">
                        <option value="${product.id}"><c:out value="${product.name}" /> </option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
```

The "rooms" list contains your room types. I assume you already know how to pass them to the jsp? If not, do you use Spring or plain Servlets?

Provide the rooms via the Controller / Servlet

```
@WebServlet("/RoomsController")
public class RoomsController extends HttpServlet{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{

        // Create in createListWithRoomTypes() a List with room types so that you can list them as a select list
        request.setAttribute("rooms", createListWithRoomTypes());

        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. My problem is that i don’t understand how implement it whit jsp. Anyway i use also servlet!

Comment: I added the controller for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have create a new Servlet: RoomsController and i paste your code, and i have done the same thing with hotelbooking.jsp. But how your code in jsp could connect with the table Hotel on my DB?

Comment: You wrote to create a createListWithRoomTypes() , how can i do?